# upload a string to an amazon s3 bucket using VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, amazon-s3

In my code, I have a string and when a user presses a button on my webpage, I want to upload the string to an s3 bucket that I own. there is one caveat, however, is that I can't write a file to the users machine because it will contain sensitive data that they shouldn't have access to. can anyone help explain the process that I should go through to make this happen? I'm very new to vb.net and this is my first attempt at uploading anything to s3. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Comment: You don't need a file, you need a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream).

Comment: [TransferUtility.Upload (Stream, string, string)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html). Get the bytes using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes([string])`